# How to change icon in button in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui Raised button and want to change the icon in the button when it is clciked.

```
<RaisedButton primary={true}><i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>EXPAND</RaisedButton>
```

[The button looks like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2skJ3.png)

Any suggestion.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your initial state set expanded=false and then:

```
<RaisedButton primary={true} 
              onClick={() => this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded})}>
   <i className={'fa ' + (this.state.expanded ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus')} aria-hidden="true"></i>
   EXPAND
</RaisedButton>
```

Comment: Worked as i wanted. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClassNames javascript library. - https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

```
let classes = classNames({
              "fa" : true,
              "fa-minus": this.state.something,
            });
```